# Sorting by date components and incrementing and decrementing only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First, the films should be sorted by increasing rating, I did it, but then when you click on the date (date only), it should be sorted by decreasing date. How can this be done?
And the second question in my code, decrement and increment work infinitely, but it is necessary that they work only once (+1 or -1 and that's it).

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      movies: [
        { id: 1, name: "Deadpool", date: 2016, time: 108, genre: 'action', rating: 5 },
        { id: 2, name: "The Avengers", date: 2012, time: 143, genre: 'action', rating: 4 },
        { id: 3, name: "Slayers", date: 2022, time: 88, genre: 'fantasy,comedy', rating: 3 },
      ]
      
    }
    this.state.movies.sort((a,b) => a.rating > b.rating ? 1 : -1);
  }
  star(i) {
    let arr = new Array(i);
    return arr.fill("*");
  }
  remove(index) {
    this.state.movies.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({});
  }
  increment(plus) {
    plus.rating = plus.rating + 1;
    this.setState({});
  }
  decrement(minus) {
    minus.rating = minus.rating - 1;
    this.setState({});
  }
  render() {
    return <>
      <h1>Cinemas</h1>
      <table className="table table-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {
              Object.keys(this.state.movies[0]).map((elem, ind) => {
                return <th key={ind}>{elem}</th>
              })

            }
            <th>stars</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            { 
              this.state.movies.map((elm,index) => {
                return <tr>
                  <td>{elm.id}</td>
                  <td>
                    {elm.name}
                    <button className="btn btn-primary ms-4" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, index)}>del</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>{elm.date}</td>
                  <td>{elm.time}</td>
                  <td>{elm.genre}</td>
                  <td>{elm.rating}</td>
                  <td>
                    {this.star(elm.rating)}
                    <button className="btn btn-primary ms-4" onClick={this.increment.bind(this, elm)}>Increment</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary ms-4" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this, elm)}>Decrement</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                
              })

            }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  }

}

export default App
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to sort by date you could use a function like the below one, and call it on click on the date cell, which transformed into a button:

```js
sortByDecreasingDate() {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    movies: this.state.movies.sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()
    )
  });
}
```

```js
<thead>
  <tr>
    {Object.keys(this.state.movies[0]).map((elem, ind) => {
      if (elem === "date") {
        return (
          <th key={ind}>
            <button onClick={() => this.sortByDecreasingDate()}>
              {elem}
            </button>
          </th>
        );
      }
      return <th key={ind}>{elem}</th>;
    })}
    <th>stars</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

[image]

And if you want the increment/decrement to work only once, you can set a `rated` on each item. You make it equal to `false` by default, then when you click on increment/decrement, you set it to `true`. And you increment/decrement only if it's `false`.